# Which is better? private static vs private

Tags: c#, .net

In this code sample:

```
public class SuperMan {
    private static bool IsProper(decimal x) {
        return x > 31.0m && x < 45.0m;
    }

    public bool CheckStuff(string a, string b, string c) {
        // lots of code, some of which introduces a variable x
        return IsProper(x) && /* other conditions */;
    }
}
```

Should IsProper(..) be a 'private static' or a 'private'. Assuming:

1. IsProper(..) doesn't need to access any instance state (even in future.)
2. We are not concerned about performance different between the two options (one of the things we should never do is guess about performance without actual measurement and optimize without the need.)

Comment: Might future versions of `IsProper` access the instance state?

Comment: Nope... I will edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *could* be static, since it doesn't seem to have to do anything with the SuperMan class nor its members. But you should ask yourself if that function belongs in that class at all.

If you're checking if decimal is a proper decimal *for SuperMan*, then it belongs there. But I wouldn't make it static in that case. Chances are that you will later need to replace that constant values with SuperMan properties.

Comment: It is private, so one can only guess it is a helper. If the same code is used elsewhere, it belongs in a base class or helper class then.

Comment: The Microsoft-provided Code Analysis tool flags this as undesirable; if a method doesn’t use any instance fields then it should be static. I don’t understand what difficulty you see in making it instance when necessary (rather than prematurely).

Comment: The Microsoft-provider Code Analysis tool doesn't know what you will change to this method in the future. If it is a function that basically tells you something about an instance, even though it uses just constants right know, you should implement it as not static. I can't make out how this method is used, but it looks like it could be such a case.

Comment: Example of the above: If I got a 'box' object, and I have only one type of box in my system, I could make its getSize method return the (constant) size of that one box. It still tells me something about the instance of that box though. I will change the implementation to using actual fields as soon as the company starts using multiple types of boxes, but I can already prepare my code for that moment, by providing the box class with a non-static getSize instance method and using that method where appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Reasons to make IsProper an instance member:

- IsProper needs another implementation in an inherited class
- IsProper might need access to members in the future

Reasons to make IsProper a static member:

- You have a small performance penalty for making it an instance member.
- If you only need to create an instance of the class to call IsProper, you would make it a static

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can be a bit faster, but on the other hand sometimes it can be harder to refactor.

Comment: How so? Could you give us an example.

Comment: @KiD0M4N, Raf is right, static is faster because there is no need to creation of static but you should use static method on immutable objects or stateless conditions to prevent from unwanted results.

Comment: If you need to create an object just to call the method, that is true, but if you got the instance already, the difference in performance is neglectable. It exists, but you don't need to worry about that, unless you are writing some top notch 4D rendering engine.